# "Python" Get particular rows of an hour from data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to get all rows of each hour or day do some calculations for them.
So i mean how to iterate over data frame and filter rows of an hour some, do calculations and then move to the next hour

Question: How to get the rows of each hour/or day?

```
df
  Date      TimeStamp    col1
20150102     20:00:00    SomeData
20150102     20:01:00    SomeData
20150102     20:02:00    SomeData
20150102     20:03:00    SomeData
20150102     20:04:00    SomeData
20150102     20:05:00    SomeData


for index, row in df.iterrows():
#grouping these rows of a min/an hour and do some calculations based on these rows
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your expected output? It's possible that you can achieve your goal with vectorized operations, which would be way faster and more readable than explicit looping.

Comment: I expect to get the rows of each hour (e.g. 20:00:00-20:59:00). I used to do such stuff with iteration but any other way is also accepted.

Comment: what "stuff" specifically are you intending to do? What calculated value(s) should accompany the rows of each hour?

Comment: I will go column by column and use the values in each row of this column to compare many thing such as Momentum, Rate of change, P/L, etc.

Comment: without concrete example data and a _specific_ description of what you intend to do with it, all I can offer is to echo the posted answer, which is as vague as the question: look into `df.groupby`. Also check out how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the rows by hour/day then you can perform calculations on the other columns.

Extracting the hours/days into another column would look something like:

```
df['Hour'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.hour
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
```

After which you would groupby with:

```
df.groupby('Hour')...
df.groupby('Day')...
```